# How to place the text in front of the image

Tags: html, css, image, text

I am a beginner in coding and I want to place the text in front of the picture.

I am using Komodo. Here is my Code:

[image: CSS]

[image: HTML]

[image: My Code]

Comment: at first, you may use css `float:left` on your `img` tag

Comment: What do you want in front of it? You can just put whatever the text in from of `<img`

Comment: There is no code in the question. There's a picture, but all I know about it is "enter image description here". Please copy and paste your code, as text, into the question, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K or click the `{ }` button.

Comment: Please, write code instead of use images in your next question. 
About your question, I think your div `#contenu` should be `position: relative`, after this, each content inside can be a `position: absolute` and you can control with `top`, `left`, etc. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tags, here is a CSS solution. Add this between your `<head></head>` tags.

```
<style>
   #contenu::after {
      content: "words";
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Hopefully you mean the `<head></head>` tags? Also, please answer good questions, with code in them.

Comment: a semicolon `;` needs to be at the end of each line.

Comment: and you did not copy the code exactly as I have it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be it, please leave a comment if you need more help.
This will position text over image and put it in center.

```
<div>
  <img src="">
  <h1>Text</h1> <!-- This will positon text over image -->
</div>
```

```
div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: <nav>
        <a href="www.instagram.com/nadah1010" target="_blank">son insta</a>
        <a href="https://vm.tiktok.com/sxRJVv" target="_blank">notre tiktok</a> 
        </nav>
       <div id="bandeau">
       <div id="contenu">
        <img src="WhatsApp_Image_2020-03-26_at_17.10.45uy-mitchell.jpg" alt="photo d'aceuil" />
        <h1>Pour ma nadette</h1>
        <h2>Mon amoureuse</h2>
        <h3>Je t'aime</h3>
        
       </div>
       </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: <html>
    <head>
        <title>Pour ma nadette</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Ce site est dedié à mon amour Nada HERRAF" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you here, but it can be implemented in many different ways.

```css
.bandeau {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  color: red;
}
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 20%;
  color: red;
}
h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="bandeau">
   <div id="contenu">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg" alt="photo d'aceuil">
      <h1>Pour ma nadette</h1>
      <h2>Mon amoureuse</h2>
      <h3>Je t'aime</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope I could help you